# Keep items permanently unread in Google Reader

Tags: google-reader

I follow a number of feeds, and sometimes there are posts I want to save for a later date. I mark them Keep Unread, but the next time I go into the feed, as soon as I scroll past those posts, the Keep Unread flag is removed. Is there any way to keep a post unread until I explicitly mark it unread?

I do have "In expanded view, mark items as read when you scroll past them." checked in my settings, and generally this is the behavior I want. I just want posts that are explicitly marked as Keep Unread to stay unread until I uncheck the Keep Unread box.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you use List View items will stay unready until you open them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately. As far as I can tell the "Keep Unread" is only temporary and works while you are in that feed. As soon as you switch or reload feeds, clicking an unread item will make it read.

However, if you want to save some posts to read later, you should "star" them by clicking the star icon at the left of each post. Then click "Starred items" on the left to see them all.

Comment: That might work. I'll give it a try and see if it does what I need it to.